# Angular Dropdown (could be just IE): strange positioning of dropdown in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm taking baby steps with Angular and writing simple stuff and testing across browsers, I have a simple script to bind a menu against a JSON string array.  I want to do the whole Angular MVC instead of Javascript DOM manipulation.

In my tests I can see a strange behaviour as to the positioning of the top of the menu in IE dependent upon which item is selected.  Anyone know how to fix this?  I would like to use an Angular friendly solution, like Bootstrap?

Menu looks good in Firefox and Chrome.

```
<html ng-app="myNoteApp">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myCarSelector">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <p>Make of car : <span ng-bind="selectedCarMake"></span></p>
        <select ng-model="selectedCarMake" ng-options="val for val in carmakes"></select>
    </div>

    <script>
        // was in separate file but pasted in for demo purposes
        var app = angular.module("myNoteApp", []);
    </script>
    <script>
        // was in separate file but pasted in for demo purposes
        app.controller("myCarSelector", function ($scope) {
            $scope.selectedCarMake = "BMW"; // default value
            $scope.carmakes = ["Audi", "BMW", "Volkswagen"];
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I like to accept answers and then move on to next question.

Here is a screen grab of the problem in IE 11
[image]

Comment: This looked fine to me, can you include an image of what you're seeing? Also which IE?

Comment: added screengrab, and its IE 11 (on Win8.1)

Comment: Nothing to do about it (the browser renders it and you don't have any control over it) except stop using a `select` and switch to a cross-browser solution like ui-select (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).

Comment: @Sergui: I am very new to Angular.  If you can post an alternative listing I can accept your answer.  (I have browsed the git hub link you've given but it is greek to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems browser default behaviour.