# How to get values of dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

Here is my HTML

```
<select class="height_selected">
      <option>Select Height</option>
      <option ng-model="userHeight" ng-init="1" value="1">123 cm</option>
      <option ng-model="userHeight" ng-init="2" value="2">125 cm</option>
      <option ng-model="userHeight" ng-init="3" value="3">124 cm</option>
</select>


<a type="button" ng-click="updateHeight()">Save</a></div>
```

In the controller i do

`userHeight = $scope.userHeight;`

But i am not getting any value.

**How can i get the value ?**

Comment: See my sample code in another question regarding a different matter

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289704/angular-dropdown-could-be-just-ie-strange-positioning-of-dropdown-in-ie
ng_model the select element and use ng-options to generate list.

ng model on the select element is how the model is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrongly used `ng-model` for options. **It is used for only inputs fields like input box, textarea, select**

[**For More Reference**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

it comes like

```
<select class="height_selected" ng-model="userHeight">
      <option>Select Height</option>
      <option  value="1">123 cm</option>
      <option  value="2">125 cm</option>
      <option  value="3">124 cm</option>
</select>
```

Now only you get the value

Answer (score 1):

put ng-model in select.
also if you want to select 1 item default than
$scope.userHeight = "/value of option/";

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller', ['$scope', controllerFunction]);

function controllerFunction($scope) {
  $scope.companies = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': "c1"
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': "c2"
  }];

  $scope.companyChange = function() {
    alert(angular.toJson($scope.company));
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <select ng-model="company" ng-options="c.name for c in companies track by c.id" ng-change="companyChange()">
    <option value="">All</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Refer more: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Hope this helps.